# Getting extreme wrong location in LocationManager?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, locationmanager, supportmapfragment

I get totally wrong location when using the LocationManager for a location. I get a Location about 500km faraway, the accuracy is around 588902. My Google Maps is showing the accurate position.

Does anyone have a idea about what the problem can be? It is the same when I use the getLastKnownLocation(). below is my code.

```
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //set map type
    //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    System.out.println("Lati >>> "+latitude + "   Longi>>>>>>> "+longitude + " accuracy + = " + myLocation.getAccuracy());
    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
```

Comment: Replace this and let me know,
`String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

Comment: give an error. cannot criteria cannot be provide to string.

Comment: Sorry that was mistake, use this
 `location = locationManager                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` rather than "provider".

Comment: I'd log more Location info such as: getProvider() (or just log the 'provider'), getTime().  Seems the assumption is Google Maps (blue dot?) is using the same Location framework; otherwise there may have been no requests to get position (which is something you probably should do anyways).